# Excel parser stuck on one row

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, loops

So I was making a quick script to loop through a bunch of sheets in an excel file (22 to be exact) and what I wanted to do was the following:

1. Open the excel sheet and open the sheet named "All" which contained a list of names and then loop through each name and do the following
2. To loop through all the other 22 sheets in the same workbook and look through each one for the name, which I knew was in the 'B' column.
3. If the name were to be found, I wanted to take all the columns in that row containing the data for that name and these columns were from A-H
4. Then copy and paste them next to the original name (same row) in the 'All sheet' while leaving a bit of a space between the original name and the others.

I wanted to do this for all 22 sheets and for the 200+ names listed in the 'All' sheet, my code is as follows:

```
import openpyxl, pprint
columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
k = 10
x = 0

def colnum_string(n):
    string = ""
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, 26)
        string = chr(65 + remainder) + string
    return string

print("Opening Workbook...")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('FileName.xlsx')
sheet_complete = wb.get_sheet_by_name("All")
row_count_all = sheet_complete.max_row

for row in range(4, row_count_all+1):
    k = 10
    cell = 'B' + str(row)
    print(cell)
    name = sheet_complete[cell].value
    for i in range(2, 23):
        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(str(1995 + i))
        row_count = sheet.max_row
        for row2 in range(2, row_count+1):
            cell2 = 'B' + str(row2)
            name2 = sheet[cell].value
            if name == name2:
                x = x + 1
                for z in range(0,len(columns)):
                    k = k + 1
                    cell_data = sheet[columns[z] + str(row2)].value
                    cell_target = colnum_string(k) + str(row)
                    sheet_complete[cell_target] = cell_data
                    wb.save('Scimago Country Ranking.xlsx')
                print("Completed " + str(x) + " Task(s)")
            break
```

The problem is that it keeps looping with the first name only, so it goes through all the names but when it comes to copying and pasting the data, it just redoes the first name so in the end, I end up with all the names in the 'All' sheet and next to each one is the data for the first name repeated over and over. I can't see what's wrong with my code but forgive me if it's a silly mistake as I'm kind of a beginner in these excel parsing scripts. print statements were for testing reasons.

P.S I know I'm using a deprecated function and I will change that, I was just too lazy to do it since it seems to still work fine and if that's the problem then please let me know.

Comment: Why do you have the loop `for row2 in range(2, row_count+1):` if you `break` after the first iteration?

Comment: I was trying to make it stop looping through the names in the sheet, once it found the first find because the name appears only once but I might've put the break in the wrong place and if so please tell me where to put it because these excel loops are really confusing to me :/

Comment: I recommend starting by having the `break` at the same indentation level as `print("Completed " + str(x) + " Task(s)")`. As @Matthias pointed out having the break where it is now will stop after the first loop regardless of if `name == name2`

Comment: I did so but still the same problem persists...